# fixing slash in a shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have a text file like this

```
REP1.bam    ./CONTROL/CONTROL.bam
```

This is a tab separated file.
I want to split the line on tab/space and store individual columns as separate array elements.

I did something like this

```
while read -r line; do arr=(${line{///}); echo ${arr[1]}; done < test.txt
```

This gives me .CONTROLCONTROL.bam and does not preserve the slashes.

How can I fix this.

Comment: `while read -ra line` to read into an array.

Comment: this outputs nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you meant `${line///}` instead of `$line{///}`. That would indeed give you `.CONTROLCONTROL.bam` since you're explicitly asking the shell to replace slashes with nothing... (`$line{///}` would just be the value of the variable, with a literal `{///}` appended.)

I'm not exactly sure why you're doing that. All you need to do, to get the two columns in two distinct variables is to use `read -r var1 var2`. Then you can store them to an array, or use them directly

```
$ while read -r foo path; do arr=("$foo" "$path"); echo "${arr[1]}"; done < test.txt
./CONTROL/CONTROL.bam
```

Or use `read -ra arr` (in Bash), to split the fields directly to an array.